# Endless Thread In Background and GC

Tags: c#

I would like to know what happens to threads which are running in background after the object gets collected by GC? Do they kill themselves or do they turn zombie process?

```
 private Thread currentDateTimer;
 private DateTime ActualDateTime;

 if (this.currentDateTimer == null)
        {
            this.currentDateTimer = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    this.ActualDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000 - (DateTime.Now.Second * 1000 + DateTime.Now.Millisecond));
                }
            }) { IsBackground = true };
            this.currentDateTimer.Start();
        }
```

The thread doesnt know when to stop.

Will this thread get killed once the object instance gets collected? Will GC collect this object ever since its the thread needs this.ActualDateTime?

I hope somebody had the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the thread delegate has captured `this`, the object will not be collected.

Since you have started it with `IsBackground = true`, it will terminate by itself when the application is shutting down.

Comment: Did I get you right the object will never get collected even if I have nothing else pointing at the object?

Comment: As @Lasse says, the thread's delegate will still point to the object so it won't get collected.

Comment: Interesting. Reminds me about the GC from actionscript 3 where tweens suddenly would not work anymore if u declared them in a local scope